# Транслировать SQL запрос в запрос LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Есть следующий SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT UserActivity.UserCompany,
    PageNameNormalized, 
    COUNT(UserActivity.PageNameNormalized) AS NumberOfVisits, 
    AVG(ISNULL(GivenServiceScore,0)) As AvgScore
FROM UserActivity
LEFT JOIN UserReviews ON PageNameNormalized = ServiceName
GROUP BY UserActivity.UserCompany, PageNameNormalized
ORDER BY UserActivity.UserCompany
```

Пытаюсь перевести этот запрос в код на LINQ, пока выходит так:

```
var select = (from a in _azdb.UserActivity
              join b in _azdb.UserReviews on a.PageNameNormalized equals b.ServiceName into temp
              from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
              orderby t.UserDO
              select new ActivityPick
              {
                UserCompany = a.UserCompany,
                PageNameNormalized = a.PageNameNormalized,
                NumberOfVisits = a.PageNameNormalized.Count(),
                AvgScore = (double)(t.GivenServiceScore.HasValue ? t.GivenServiceScore : 0),
              }).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

С этим кодом есть две проблемы:

1. NumberOfVisits считает неправильно (должен считать количество строк, где текущий t.UserCompany = a.UserCompany)
2. GivenServiceScore, как написано в запросе на SQL, должен считать среднее значение GivenServiceScore для конкретного PageNameNormalized, но я не придумал, как это правильно прописать в моем LINQ-запросе (возможно, вынести этот параметр в отдельную переменную?).

Помогите исправить код на LINQ, чтобы он соответствовал SQL-запросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли группировку. Нельзя повторить запрос не следуя важным операторам.

```cs
var query = 
    from a in _azdb.UserActivity
    join b in _azdb.UserReviews on a.PageNameNormalized equals b.ServiceName into temp
    from b in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group t by new { a.UserCompany, a.PageNameNormalized } into g
    select new ActivityPick
    {
        UserCompany = g.Key.UserCompany,
        PageNameNormalized = g.Key.PageNameNormalized,
        NumberOfVisits = g.Count(),
        AvgScore = (double)g.Average(x => x.GivenServiceScore ?? 0)
    };

query = query.OrderBy(x => x.UserCompany);
```